# How do I get a string displaying the keypress of the function (like where-is shows)?

Tags: key-bindings, keystrokes

```
(where-is 'zap-to-char) ;; Prints ("zap-to-char is on M-znil")   
(where-is-internal 'zap-to-char) ;; [134217850] ;;; this number seems like junk to me!
```

I would like a function that returns `M-z` I imagine it would be something like `(keypress-of 'zap-to-char)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Convert between readable key description (string, such as `"M-z"`) and key sequence (vector or string, such as `[134217850]`, `[?\M-z]`, `"\M-z"`, these three are the identical as key sequence):

```el
(key-description [134217850])
    ⇒ "M-z"

(kbd "M-z")
    ⇒ [134217850]
```

---

If you read the source code of `where-is`, you should be able to think of something like following

```el
(mapconcat #'key-description (where-is-internal 'zap-to-char) ", ")
    ⇒ "M-z"
```

Answer (score 0):

I want to do this often, so this might be too inefficient a way:

```
(defun get-keys (function)
  (with-current-buffer (get-buffer-create "temp-buffer")
    (erase-buffer)
    (where-is function t)
    (let* ((regex (pcre-to-elisp/cached "(,\\s|\\s\\()"))
           (results (s-split regex (buffer-string)))
           (take-until (- (length results) 1)))
      (subseq results 0 take-until)))) 

(get-keys 'ido-kill-buffer) ;; ("M-m b k" "C-x k")
```

Comment: Other variants will be accepted. Perhaps one that is a variation on `where-is` in `help.el`?